# Rephrasing "Audience-minded" or "Audience-attentive"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, phrase-requests, flow, alliteration

I am struggling to find the best flowing combination of the words "Audience-minded."

I would preferably like to have it read "x-minded". Although, I am not opposed to a synonym that better flows. By flow, a good rule of thumb would be the phrase, "Editorial-minded" as that flows very nicely in my eyes.

The sentence itself reads as of right now as: "Audience-minded digital producer and..."

I basically would like it to state, that this person keeps the viewership in high regard when completing his work.

Bonus points if it's alliterative.

If anyone could come up with something better, it would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: This is all very subjective, but I would go with *audience-focussed*

Comment: T.A. N, in terms of what you seemed to have been hoping for, JonLarby seems to have said it all.

Then, did you notice *I would preferably like to have it read "x-minded"* seems to read backwards? That is, you were looking at *Audience-minded* and *Audience-attentive* and presumably *Audience-X* but then it's *X-minded*?